How to Launch MS Paint 3D by Powershell without Passing it to Old MS Paint Application
Apparently Windows (only 10?) installed some troublesome updates that make it impossible to open Paint 3D using old microsoft paint environment. To make things worse, Paint 3D does not have an .exe address to use right click context menu to "open with" images.
I searched and apparently the old method to launch paint 3d by powershell was using old ms paint to pass the argument, something like:
Start-Process -FilePath "mspaint" -ArgumentList """C:\IMAGE_PATH.jpg /ForceBootstrapPaint3D"""

Unfortunately, above code too makes powershell to go to windows store. Does anyone know a method to launch paint 3D by powershell directly? Thank you.

I'm on Windows 10 21H2 and when I ran your command it launched in regular paint. Perhaps something in your environment or group policies is causing launch of the store?

@user8168912, see below link if you are interested. it's a common problem after a certain update and till now the only solution was to uninstall said update.
https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsHelp/comments/1d31v3y/win10_youll_need_a_new_app_to_open_this_mspaint/
Nevertheless, I really wanted to know if there is way to call paint 3D directly. Thank you anyway.
